# Insert Multiple rows to Sqlite Database; It hangs

Tags: android, file, sqlite

I have tried using SQLiteDatabaseBrowser to make my database file however it always seems to crash when I try to execute multiple SQL insert statements, and since I want to insert a few hundred entries of data, executing "INSERT INTO table..." one by one doesn't seem practical to me.

Is there a better program for creating SQLiteDatabase files?

The reason I want to create a file is so that I can have it in my assets folder of my Android App and simply copy the file into the database folder of the app, and therefore time is saved from having to execute a few hundreds lines of code in the actual program to insert the data.

Comment: @njzk2 Please read the question again he is not doing it programitically but yes using the Sqlite Browser then it hangs and also Sqlite browser supports multiple queries separated with semicolon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest you rather than putting multiple insert queries in a row

use import/export function

Note: As per my experience Sqlite does not properly handle exception while executing queries so while executing queries any error will put it unresponsive so take your query to anyother database and then export in form of CSV(Recommended) or SQL then use **IMPORT** feature

[image: Import Export]